# Maximum sum increasing subsequence O(nlogn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

Given an array A of N positive integers. Find the sum of maximum sum of strictly increasing subsequence of the given array.
[Check it out](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-sum-increasing-subsequence/0)
Ex.:-
For Array [1 101 2 3 100 4 5] answer should be 106.

I have written a code that fails on some test-cases. Can Anyone help.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n   = int(input())
    lst = list(map(int,input().split()))

    dp     = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
    total  = [0 for i in range(n)]
    parent = [-1 for i in range(n)]
    dp[0]  = None

    length = 0
    ans    = -float('inf')

    for i in range(n):
        low  = 1
        high = length
        ele  = lst[i]

        while(low<=high):
            mid = (low+high)//2
            if(ele<=lst[dp[mid]]):
                high = mid-1
            else:
                low = mid+1

        pos = low
        parent[i] = dp[pos-1]

        if(parent[i]==None):
            total[i] = lst[i]
        else:
            total[i] = total[parent[i]]+lst[i]

        dp[pos] = i
        if(pos>length):
            length = pos
    # print(total)
    print(max(total))
```

Comment: `[1 101 2 3 100 4 5]`  => either 102 (1+101) or  105(2+3+100)  - where do you get 106 ? And why  binary-search?

Comment: 1+2+3+100=>106 and the code in the while loop is part of binary search

Comment: Couldn't we just have `dp[i] = A[i] + dp[m]` where `m` is the index of the next lower element to the left of `A[i]`? (Indexes of the next lower element on the left could be saved beforehand in `O(n)`.) Is there any reason the next lower element on the left's cell wouldn't hold the highest sum achievable before adding `A[i]`? (I guess we want the next *positive* lower element to the left...)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 

int getSum(int BITree[], int index)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (index > 0) {
        sum = max(sum, BITree[index]);
        index -= index & (-index);
    }
    return sum;
}
 

void updateBIT(int BITree[], int newIndex,
               int index, int val)
{
    while (index <= newIndex) {
        BITree[index] = max(val, BITree[index]);
        index += index & (-index);
    }
}
 

int maxSumIS(int arr[], int n)
{
    int newindex = 0, max_sum;
 
    map<int, int> uniqueArr;
 
   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uniqueArr[arr[i]] = 0;
    }
 
    
    for (map<int, int>::iterator it = uniqueArr.begin();
         it != uniqueArr.end(); it++) {
 
       
        newindex++;
 
        uniqueArr[it->first] = newindex;
    }
 
   
    int* BITree = new int[newindex + 1];
 
   
    for (int i = 0; i <= newindex; i++) {
        BITree[i] = 0;
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       
        max_sum = getSum(BITree, uniqueArr[arr[i]] - 1);
 
        updateBIT(BITree, newindex,
                 uniqueArr[arr[i]], max_sum + arr[i]);
    }
 
    return getSum(BITree, newindex);
}
 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 101, 2, 3, 100, 4, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "Maximum sum is = " << maxSumIS(arr, n);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. Visit the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for more details.